# Cucumber not recognizing tags

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a strange issue with Cucumber not recognizing tags. I want to exclude one scenario from executing but it is still being executed. I am using cucumber 6.10.2 version (io.cucumber).

So the scenario is:

```
@tag1
  Scenario Outline: Attempt to Create Contract                
    Given I delete all test data for <some collection name>
    And I delete all test data for <other collection name>
```

My runner class is:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

        @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
        @CucumberOptions(
                features = "src/test/java/resources"
                , glue = {"stepDefinitions"}
                , plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports",
                "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html",
                "html:target/cucumber-report.html",
                "json:target/cucumber.json"}
                , tags = "not @tag1"
    
    )
    
    public class RuneCukeTest {
    }
```

I also tried different syntax for tags such as:

```
tags = ~"@tag1"
tags = "~@tag1"
```

but none is working. (even if I try to run only this tag).
it is not allowing me to type it this way probably because of the version:

```
tags = {"@tag1"}
```

What I found under "tags" documentation is:

```
  String tags() default "";
```

and example above it "@smoke and not @fast"

> NOTES:

I am using few .feature files and I want to execute only one and skip only 1 scenario from it. I am trying both - to execute it from the runner class with the @CucumberOptions and by right clicking on the .feature file itself. Nothing is working...

Comment: Did you try `tags = "{@feature not @tag1)"`? (where `@feature` is the tag used at the very top of the feature file). you could also try with the tilde character.

Comment: yep, it is not working yet :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works for me
tags = "@Integration or @Wip and not @SmokeTest and not @Ignore"

Comment: I think it is more accurate to be 
 "(@Integration or @Wip) and not @SmokeTest and not @Ignore"
Where "or" is equal to "and" for some reason....

Answer (score 0):

Well, today I kinda find partial solution.
I've added 2 tags - one to skip and one to run (different scenario).

```
tags = "not @Opportunities" + "@Testing123"
```

It works from the terminal with the following:

```
mvn clean
mvn test "-Dcucumber.filter.tags= not @Opportunities and @Testing123"
```

I've managed to make it work only once starting the runner class but only after the execution from the terminal was done. I've tried to run it again using the same algorithm but without success.

Comment: That's bizarre.

Comment: yep, I am still searching for a normal solution

Answer (score 0):

I was baffled why my tests are not being picked up and found something interesting.

I was populating the below environment variable (I am using gitlab pipeline)

```
CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS: "@SmokeTest and @integration not @ignore"
```

this in turn is passed to gradle task with

```
-Dcucumber.filter.tags= not @SmokeTest and @integration not @ignore
```

Now, as I was writing the fresh pipeline, there will be some tests with @SmokeTest and some with @integration

However at the time of running this job, my feature file didn't have any tests with @integration

Now here comes the interesting part, if you put and non existing tag in your filter criteria with **and** clause it doesn't work.
@ignore is internal to cucumber so that doesn't cause a problem if you have no tests marked with @ignore.

So it was not picking any tests to run.

I haven't tried but I think or clause might have worked for non existing tag